# Displaying diffrent series in the same chart using swtchart

Tags: java, charts, swtchart

I have a problem in which I'm trying to display a few types of data in a single chart and it's not going well.
First of all, I have one series of data that is supposed to be displayed as a line chart, and then I have to add some bar charts. The number of bars depends on other conditions but it will be a number between 3 and 5. Each bar series is supposed to be created as a new IBarSeries because I have to check if each of them is bigger than the line chart value and change its color if true.
The main function that creates char data looks like that

```
private void setChartData( final List<double[]> ListOfAllSeries )
   {   
       NumberFormat integerFormat = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance();
       
       ILineSeries lineSeries = (ILineSeries) chart.getSeriesSet().createSeries( SeriesType.LINE, "LineSeries" );
       lineSeries.setYSeries( ListOfAllSeries.get( 1 ) );
       lineSeries.setVisibleInLegend(false);

       for(int i = 0; i < ListOfAllSeries.get(0).length; i++)
       {
           createBarSeries("BarSeries " + i,new double[] { series1.get(0)[i]}, new double[] {i},ListOfAllSeries.get(1)[i]);
       }        

       xAxis.getTick().setFormat( integerFormat );
       chart.getAxisSet().adjustRange();
       chart.getAxisSet().getXAxis(0).setRange(new Range(-0.5, ListOfAllSeries.get(0).length - 0.5));
       chart.redraw();
   }
```

Index 0 of ListOfAllSeries always contains all bars data and in index 1 is line series data.

And here is createBarSeries function that creates bar series

```
    private void createBarSeries(String seriesName, double[] yValues, double[] xValues, double lineValue)
    {
        IBarSeries barSeries = (IBarSeries) chart.getSeriesSet().createSeries(SeriesType.BAR,seriesName);
        barSeries.setYSeries(yValues);
        barSeries.setXSeries(xValues);
        barSeries.setBarColor(yValues[0] > lineValue ? redColor : blueColor);
        barSeries.setBarWidth(50);
        barSeries.setBarPadding(0);
    }
```

The problem is that bars, excluding the center bar, are shifted on the x-axis. For example, if there are supposed to be 3 bars, the center one will be in place but every other will be shifted from place and I want them to be exactly in the right spot. I tried different technics but nothing seems to work.